# Can a Postgres LIKE statement return an exact match?

Tags: postgresql, like, string-searching

I'm trying to search a Postgres table using LIKE and %, but the query is not returning results.

The column `local_username` will contains values formatted like: `username@domain.local` OR `username@domain`.

My query is searching this one column based on both the `username` and domain sections.

An example query is below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE local_username LIKE 'username%' 
  AND local_username LIKE '%domain%';
```

I'm concerned that, because there may be no characters after domain in the query, the second % is going to cause it to not return any results, since the % causes it to search for more characters, which in the case of the above query are not present.

Is there another keyword other than LIKE that I should be using? Or do I need to check each possibility (example below).

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE local_username LIKE 'username%' 
AND (local_username LIKE '%domain%' OR local_username LIKE '%domain');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%` will match any sequence of characters, **including none**. So this is a match:

```
SELECT 'match' WHERE 'username@domain.com' like '%.com%';
-- Result: match
```

If you have the *exact* username and the *exact* domain you can use the following filter:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE 
    local_username = 'username@domain' OR   -- Exact match
    local_username LIKE 'username@domain.%';    -- Exact match until dot
```

If you have partial filters, you will have to add a few more `%` (place depends your needs):

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE 
    local_username LIKE 'username%@domain' OR   -- Exact domain ending
    local_username LIKE 'username%@domain.%';   -- Exact domain ending until dot
```